# "...In not only..." vs. "...not only in..."?

Tags: prepositions, word-order

I'm confused about placing the preposition *in* with the words *not only* in a sentence. My sentence is:

> The paper helps us in not only selection of the methodology but also other important factors....

Should the *in* be before or after *not only*?

Comment: "not only in" is acceptable, I think, but I find the following nicer: *The paper helps us not only select a methodology but also in other important ways."  Or *The paper is helpful not only in selecting a methodology but also in other important ways."

Answer (score 1):

*in* can be placed before or after *not only*

Placed before

> The paper helps us **in** not only selection of the methodology but also
>   other important factors....

Placed after

> The paper helps us not only **in** selection of the methodology but also
>   **in** other important factors....

Difference :  For the sake of parallelism you have to repeat *in* after *but also*